# How can I verify if my spark-dataframe is actually being populated?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a script to perform some ETL on a database. 
I have an existing dataframe that I have populated from a table. 
I was able to get the number of rows in the dataframe and double-checked that it matched with the number of rows in the database

```
var originalDF = spark.table("XYZ").select(" ").toDF(" ")
println(originalDF.count())
```

Now I'm trying to map each row of the original table to perform some ETL operation using `val transformedDF = originalDF.map(dataTransform(_))`
However, now even though I have a print statement that tries to print out the number of rows in the finalDF, the interpreter skips this statement and nothing prints out. Even the last print statement that denotes "Finished Transform" doesn't print out. My `dataTransform`  does something very simple (made it simpler to test)

```
println(finalDF.count())
println("Finished Transform")
```

Does anybody know why this might be the case that statements after my map operation are skipped. I know scala has lazy evaluation and so I suspect that the map operation might not be taking place actually.

```
def dataTransform (tr:Row): Record.BookRecord = {
    val field1 =  tr.getAs[String]("field1")
    val field2 =  tr.getAs[String]("field2")
    val field3 =  tr.getAs[String]("field3")

    Record.BookRecord(
      field_1 = field1,
      field_2 = field2,
      field_3 = field3
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you post source, just to be sure?

Comment: I also believe your issue to be linked with spark's lazy evaluation. I cannot be certain though. Could you post a minimal reproducible example so that we can help you better?